# Create SQL table name with date included

Tags: java, android, sql, android-sqlite

Is there way to include the date as part of the table name in android?

Right now this is how I am creating the table:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// TABLE INFORMATTION
public static final String TABLE_DATE = "date";
public static final String SD_ID = "_id";
public static final String DATE_SHOTS = "shots";

// DATABASE INFORMATION
static final String DB_NAME = ".DB";
static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

// TABLE CREATION STATEMENT
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table "
        + TABLE_DATE + "(" + SD_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + DATE_SHOTS + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null,DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DATE);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Obviusly where it says `static final String DB_NAME = ".DB";` I would like to have the name before the .db.

This was the function I was goign to use to get the date:

```
    private String getDateTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

but it says that it cannot be referenced from static content. I know what that means but I can't do

`getDateTime gDT = new getDateTime();

Any help would be awesome thanks!

Comment: You don't want to do it.  Create a single table and make the date a separate column.

Comment: Why do you want so many tables in a database?